# How to get the values from a dictionary nested within two lists?

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, nested-lists

I'm still familiarizing with python and using APIs. I extracted the following data from an API:

```
    [[{'term': 'Boys', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300247598'},
  {'term': 'Fish', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300266085'},
  {'term': 'Boats', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300178749'}],
 [{'term': 'Bears', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300266516'}],
 None,
  [{'term': 'Interiors',
   'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300391239'},
  {'term': 'Jewelry', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300209286'},
  {'term': 'Couples', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300379217'},
  {'term': 'Men', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300025928'},
  {'term': 'Women', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300025943'},
  {'term': 'Weights and Measures',
   'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300386648'}],
...]
```

I would like to extract the values within the 'term' keys (but preserving the sublists) in a final list like this:

```
[['Boys','Fish','Boats'],['Bears'],['Interiors','Jewlery','Couples','Men','Women','Weights and Measures']...]
```

Whenever I try to Iter through the lists like this:

```
for x in tags:
    for y in x:
        print (y['term'])
```

I get the following result:

```
Boys
Fish
Boats
Bears

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-f2ff632ad612> in <module>
     11 
     12 for x in tags:
---> 13     for y in x:
     14         print (y['term'])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How can I solve it? Thank you in advance c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the data into a list of same structure check for `None` and only add things if you have data:

```
data = [[{'term': 'Boys', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300247598'},
         {'term': 'Fish', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300266085'},
         {'term': 'Boats', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300178749'}],
        [{'term': 'Bears', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300266516'}], 
        None,
        [{'term': 'Interiors', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300391239'},
         {'term': 'Jewelry', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300209286'},
         {'term': 'Couples', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300379217'},
         {'term': 'Men', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300025928'},
         {'term': 'Women', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300025943'},
         {'term': 'Weights and Measures', 'AAT_URL': 'http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300386648'}]]

result = []
for inner_list in data:
    if inner_list:  # None and [] are falsy, ignore them

        # got something, add a new empty list to add things into
        result.append([])
        for d in inner_list:
            # add all dicts term to the last item of result
            result[-1].append(d["term"])  

print(result)
```

will output:

```
[['Boys', 'Fish', 'Boats'], ['Bears'], 
 ['Interiors', 'Jewelry', 'Couples', 'Men', 'Women', 'Weights and Measures']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `x` against `None` before iterating through it:

```
for x in tags:
    if x is not None:
        for y in x:
            print (y['term'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see there is also an element of None in the data you have extracted from API. So you will have to check you do not encounter that while iterating.

```
for x in tags:
    if(x is not None):
        for y in x:
            print(y['term'])
```

This will take care of the problem

Answer (score 0):

first filter out None and then use map function

```
    data = [
        [
            {"term": "Boys", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300247598"},
            {"term": "Fish", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300266085"},
            {"term": "Boats", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300178749"},
        ],
        [{"term": "Bears", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300266516"}],
        None,
        [
            {"term": "Interiors", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300391239"},
            {"term": "Jewelry", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300209286"},
            {"term": "Couples", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300379217"},
            {"term": "Men", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300025928"},
            {"term": "Women", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300025943"},
            {"term": "Weights and Measures", "AAT_URL": "http://vocab.getty.edu/page/aat/300386648"},
        ],
    ]


    result = map(lambda x: list(map(lambda i: i["term"], x)), filter(lambda x: x is not None, data))
    print(list(result))
```